# Iterator java nested loop

Tags: java

I've a question: there is a way to increment an iterator directly into nested loop?
Example

```
while(budgets.iterator().hasNext()){
    if(budgets.iterator().next().getTipoBudget()!="I"){
        if(budgets.size()<maxInviate){
            for(i=0; i<maxInviate ;i++){
                if(budgetArray[i]==0 && budgets.iterator().hasNext()){
                    budgetArray[i] = budgets.iterator().next().getBudgetField();

                }
            }
            i=0;
            Set budgetSet = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(budgetArray));
            Integer min = Collections.min(budgetSet);
            valueAdw = valueAdw + min;
            for(i=0; i<maxInviate; i++){
                budgetArray[i] = budgetArray[i] - valueAdw;
            }
        }else{
            valueAdw = null;
            valueAdwEnd = null;
            campaigns.addLast(new Campaign(valueAdw, valueAdwEnd, (long) adwordsBudget.getZona().getAdwordsCode()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It can be sad that calling next() is equal to "increment".

Comment: Also, when you call iterator().next() you should actually store the returned Object somewhere so you can use it. Alternately use the fancy for construct which is much nicer: "for (Budget b : budgets){}"

Comment: add budgets.iterator().next() in else block.

Comment: Each call to `budgets.iterator()` will give you a brand new, unincremented iterator.

Comment: `budgets.iterator().next().getTipoBudget()!="I"` should be `budgets.iterator().next().getTipoBudget().equals("I");`

Comment: @Pau Kiat Wee Almost perfect, but there is `!=` not `==`. It should be `(!budgets.iterator().next().getTipoBudget().equals("I"))`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `budgets.iterator()` returns a new `Iterator` every time, so `budgets.iterator().hasNext()` moves the pointer in an `Iterator` that you're not using any more.
Define

```
Iterator iterator = budgets.iterator();
```

and use that in the rest of the code.

Also @Sachin J is right, you have to write iterator.next() in the else block, too.
Also @Marko Topolnik sorry I just saw your comment, I didn't try to steal your idea.